# C# Parallel.ForEach opening up too many connections from the pool

Tags: c#, mysql, foreach, parallel-processing, mariadb

The full error received is this:

```
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.
```

So I have a parallel foreach:

```
      Parallel.ForEach(fields, item =>
        {
            item.SysInvoiceID = _destinationRepo.GetMySQLSystemID(item);
        });
```

Which calls a method which looks like this:

```
   public int GetMySQLSystemID(CustomFieldBase GenericCustomField)
        {
            CustomField customField = GenericCustomField as CustomField;
            int sys_InvoiceID = 0;
            using (MySqlConnection mySQLConnection = new MySqlConnection("Server=web01;Database=wmp;User Name=root;Password=TotallyMyPWord"))
            {
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = $@"SELECT Sys_InvoiceID FROM tblsys_naturalkey_lu WHERE CompanyCode = '{customField.CompanyCode}' AND InvoiceNo = '{customField.InvoiceNo}'
                                            AND LineItemNo = '{customField.LineItemNo}' AND FiscalYear = '{customField.FiscalYear}'";
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Connection = mySQLConnection;

                    mySQLConnection.Open();

                    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (reader.Read())
                        {
                            sys_InvoiceID = (int)reader["Sys_InvoiceID"];
                        }
                    }
                    mySQLConnection.Close();
                }
            }
            return sys_InvoiceID;
        }
```

When looking at the MySQL Session manager I can see that the `Parallel.ForEach` keeps adding connections until I had my limit.

I'm closing my MySQLConnection though, why does it keep creating connections until the max limit?

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach` is specifically designed for *CPU* bound work, not IO work.

Comment: What Servy said.  Does this approach even produce any benefit for you?  You should probably measure this on a handful of threads and see if there's even any performance improvement.  See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: This is true; you shouldn't use `Parallel.ForEach()` for IO-bound work.

Comment: I understand that it shouldnt be used for IO work. But it runs a lot faster than a synchronous foreach as it's performing at least 4 queries at any one time

Comment: @AndrewKilburn You can perform the queries in parallel in lots of different ways that don't require using `Parallel.ForEach`.  Use the right tool for the right job, and `Parallel`, isn't the right tool for creating parallelism in this context.  You don't even need any additional threads at all, just make the operation asynchronous and start multiple queries before others complete.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't put any limit on the number of parallel operations created by `Parallel.ForEach()`, so it will be creating an unbounded number of SQL connections.

You can fix this by [specifying the maximum degree of parallelism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Parallel.ForEach(fields, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8 }, item =>
{
    item.SysInvoiceID = _destinationRepo.GetMySQLSystemID(item);
});
```

However (as others have pointed out), you shouldn't be using `Parallel.ForEach()` for IO-bound work in any case.

Comment: But it's not closing the connections. Even if I gave it a lower amount of cores, it would still reach that point eventually wouldnt it?

Comment: @AndrewKilburn It will be closing the connections, but only when the command has executed - and you are launching commands before the earlier ones have completed. If you launch commands faster than they complete, you'll eventually run out of handles.

Comment: So limiting the parallelism will still cause the same issue wont it? It will just take longer to reach the limit

Comment: @AndrewKilburn No, because it limits the maximum number of simultaneous connections to whatever you set `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` to. No more threads that that will be allowed to run simultaneously; when the limit is reached, `Parallel.ForEach()`  will wait for a previous thread to terminate before launching a new one.

Comment: I've set the MaxDegreeOfParallelism to 100. 50 less than our max connection limit, this runs a lot faster than not in parallel

Comment: I would not set `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` more than the number of CPU cores/threads you have.  Otherwise, they will just be stumbling over each other, and not finishing the overall task any faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SqlConnection.ClearPool method, but still I would suggest to reuse you connection if this is something that must be done through parallel loop. As others mentioned you shouldn't be doing this.

For example, open connection before starting parallel loop. Then dispose after everything is done.